# jQuery ajax works once, but each time thereafter loads the href through browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a click handler that reads the href attribute of an a tag and loads the new content via ajax.  The function returns false so it doesn't follow the href url.  This works once, but each time thereafter, the function does not appear to get called and the content is not loaded asynchronously, but instead follows the link in the browser.

```
$ ("document").ready( function () {
          $(".post_update").click( function () {
              $("#dashboard_content").html(ajax_load).load($(this).attr('href'));
              return false;
          });
});

<a href="{{ path('post_update', {"id":post.id}) }}" class="post_update">Edit</a>
```

Comment: ajax_load is just the string "Loading..." and .post_update is inside #dashboard_content, yes

Comment: What is this "{{ path('post_update', {"id":post.id}) }}" going to do?

Comment: That's just a twig function that prints out a URL in the format http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/post/update/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should not use document as a string its an object itself try the belwo code.

Since the link is inside dashboard container you should use live in this case.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
          $("a.post_update").live('click',  function () {
              $("#dashboard_content").html(ajax_load).load($(this).attr('href'));
              return false;
          });
});
```

Comment: I changed it so document isn't a string, but this still only works the first time.

Comment: Try now I have edited my answer, I didnt knew the link is inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

If `.post_update` is inside `#dashboard_content`, the problem is that the element to which the event handler was bound, is now gone. The simplest solution, is to use the `jQuery.live` method. So your code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".post_update").live("click", function (e) {
        $("#dashboard_content").html(ajax_load).load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```